# Does $f(0)=0$ and $\left|f^\prime(x)\right|\leq\left|f(x)\right|$ imply $f(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(0)=0$ for all real numbers $x$, $\left|f^\prime(x)\right|\leq\left|f(x)\right|$. Can $f$ be a function other than the constant zero function?

I coudn't find any other function satisfying the property. The bound on $f^\prime(x)$ may mean that $f(x)$ may not change too much but does it mean that $f$ is constant?

I thought for a while and found that $f^\prime(0)=0$ and by using mean value theorem, if $x\neq0$ then there's a real number $y$ between $0$ and $x$ such that $\left|f(x)\right|=\left|xf^\prime(y)\right|\leq\left|xf(y)\right|$. Anything further?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399394/if-left-fx-right-leq-a-fx-beta-then-f-is-a-constant-function?rq=1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is some real number with $f(x)=0$, and let $y\in [x-1/2,x+1/2]$ be such that $|f(y)|$ is maximized. Then the mean value theorem implies there is some $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that
$$
2\cdot |f(y)|\leq \frac{|f(y)|}{|y-x|}=\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right|=|f'(z)|\leq |f(z)|\leq |f(y)|,
$$
which implies $f(y)=0$. We have shown that $f(x)$ implies $f$ is $0$ on $[x-1/2,x+1/2]$, so $f$ must be identically $0$.

Comment: It is worth noting that the vanishing property at some point, like $f(0)=0$, is crucial. Without this property, the conclusion is no longer true. For example, the function $e^{-x}$ serves, which is not even constant.

Answer (score 15):

Let $F(x)=|f(x)|$. Then if $x>0$
$$
F(x)=\Bigl|\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt\Bigr|\le\int_0^x|f'(t)|\,dt\le\int_0^x|f(t)|\,dt=\int_0^xF(t)\,dt.
$$
From here we get
$$
\Bigl(e^{-x}\int_0^xF(t)\,dt\Bigr)'=e^{-x}\Bigl(F(x)-\int_0^xF(t)\,dt\Bigr)\le0.
$$
Thus, $e^{-x}\int_0^xF(t)\,dt$ is decreasing. Since its value at $x=0$ is $0$ and $e^{-x}>0$, we see that $\int_0^xF(t)\,dt\le0$ for all $x>0$. Since $F\ge0$, this implies that $F(x)=0$ for all $x>0$.

A similar reasoning applies if $x<0$.

Comment: Impressive! But it's not clear to me why $f^\prime$ is integrible.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari You are right. I assumed that $f$ is the integral of $f'$. But since $f$ is differentiable everywhere, $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable, and the argument works (if I remember well my measure theory).

Comment: It isn't true that the derivative of an everywhere-differentiable function is Lebesgue integrable. A counterexample is $f(x)=x^2 \sin(x^{-2})$, extended by continuity at $x=0$.

Comment: I forgot to add the condition $f'$ is (locally) bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing the idea that I mentioned after proposing the question:
Let's define  $y_1:=y$. By the mean value theorem there's a real number $y_2$  between $0$ and $y_1$ such that $\left|f(y_1)\right|\leq\left|y_1f^\prime(y_2)\right|\leq\left|y_1f(y_2)\right|$ so $\left|f(x)\right|\leq\left|xy_1f(y_2)\right|\leq\left|x^2f(y_2)\right|$. Continuing this way, we inductively conclude that for every positive integer $n$, there's a real number $y_n$ between $0$ and $x$ such that $\left|f(x)\right|\leq\left|x^nf(y_n)\right|$. So if $0<x<1$, using the fact that $f$ is bounded on a bounded interval, we take the limit of the right-hand side of the last equation as $n$ tends to infinity and conclude that $f(x)=0$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have $f(x)=0$ for $0\leq x\leq1$. Now, if $m$ is a positive integer, the function $g(x)=f(x+m)$ has the property $\left|g^\prime(x)\right|\leq\left|g(x)\right|$. This lets us to prove that $f(x)=0$ for $m\leq x\leq m+1$ inductively. The function $h(x)=f(-m+1-x)$ can be treated in the same manner and that allows us to prove $f(x)=0$ for every real number $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I am just outlining an alternate approach to visualize what is actually going on. I am aware that it is not completely rigorous as it depends on a infinitesimal quantity.  $\space $Suppose $x$ is time and $f(x)$ is the position of a body on the real line. It is given that the magnitude of velocity i.e. speed is less than equal to its distance from origin in magnitude. At time $0$, the speed is $0$ as the particle is at $0$ distance from the origin, so in next $\mathrm d t$ times, where $\mathrm d t \to 0$, it will move $0 \cdot \mathrm d t=0$ distance. In next step of length $\mathrm d t$ also, it will not move because it still has zero speed because it is at zero distance from the origin. So the body is stuck at the origin. So for all times, the position is zero. So, $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: This intuition is misleading. The same way of thought would go if the problem was stated as $ | f ' ( x ) | \le 2 \sqrt { | f ( t ) | } $, which is a completely different situation, as there is the nonzero function $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 $ satisfying it.

Comment: You are right! Thanks for pointing it out, should I delete my answer?

Comment: I don't think so. It's good to have such things pointed out.

Comment: I'm thinking when would that kind of thinking work. I'm trying to search the other solutions for insight, and for example find out that if the problem was stated as my above comment, which parts would not work.

Comment: I am also thinking about the same! I think the first problem is that such a $dt$ doesn't exist only in reality. Some positive quantity less than any other positive quantity. So probably need to reformulate it in terms of formal limit.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. One can make sense of infinite and infinitesimal numbers in disciplines like [nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis) and [smooth infinitesimal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis), where everything works perfectly well. The former is a classical theory, and the latter is a nonclassical one. The problem with that kind of thinking is that we usually tend to forget about the fact that such infinitesimals are supposed to measure small LINEAR changes in variables.