# Is it true $ f'(x)\le f(x) \implies f(x)=0$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis

According to Exc. 24 Sec. 4.3 of the book Advanced Calculus by Fitzpatrick,

> Let the function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ have second derivatives and with $f(0)=0$ and $$ f'(x)\le f(x) \ \  \ \ \text{for all} \ x \ \text{in} \ \mathbb R.$$ Is $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$?

My analysis is that since for any $x_0$ we have $f'(x_0) \le f(x_0) \implies \lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - f(x_0) \le 0 \implies \dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - f(x_0) \le 0$ using the fact that a convergent sequence in $(-\infty, 0]$ converges to a number in $(-\infty, 0]$. So, for $x_0=0$ we conclude that $f(x) \le 0$ for $x\ge 0$ and $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x\le 0$.

And as I couldn't see any sign of $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, I looked for a function with the mentioned characteristics, and lucky I found $f(x)= -\sinh x$ by which $f'(x)\le f(x)$ implies $-e^{-x} \le 0$ which is true for all $x\in \mathbb R$ !

My question is that how could I have accomplished the argument without guessing a counterexample to **prove** that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ is not the only possible solution for $f(x)$? [The book says the function has the second derivative so there should be some use of it perhaps but I didn't use it].

Comment: You can't prove that "$f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ can't be true", because it **can** be true.

Comment: @Corvus, I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: There is an inherent asymmetry in "prove or disprove the existence of ..." problems. To show that something doesn't exist, you need a proof; but to show that something does exist, you only need to display an example of that something. So in my opinion, seeking a "proof" of an existence statement but not wanting to give an example is the wrong instinct to develop.

Comment: You doesn't need to **guess** a counterexample, you can simply compute it. Translate your differential inequation $f'(x)\le f(x)$ to a differential equation, say, $f'(x)+1=f(x), f(0)=0$ and just solve it.

Comment: Your implication $\lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - f(x_0) \le 0 \implies \dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - f(x_0) \le 0$ is incorrect. A function of $x$ can tend to a nonpositive limit without always being nonpositive.

Comment: counterexample $f'(x)<0, f(x)>0. f(x)=e^{-x}$

Comment: @GregMartin, yes I mistaken by the reverse implication; the correct is $\forall x : \dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - f(x_0) \le 0 \implies \lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - f(x_0) \le 0$, due to the closeness of $(-\infty, 0]$.

Comment: The correct question is $|f'(x)| \leq |f(x)|$ and $f(0) = 0$ implies $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1498898/72031 another version is as follows: if $f'(x) \leq f(x), f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$ then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \geq 0$. But as your question stands there can be counterexamples.

Answer (score 1):

You just solve the differential equation $y'-y=f'-f:=\phi.$ Clearly, $f$ is a solution.
And, by solving this equation, you find that  $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\mbox{ } f(x)=e^{x}\int_{0}^{x}\phi(t)e^{-t}dt$$ which is non negative for $x\geq 0$ and non positive for $x\leq 0$. This is the only thing you can say!
The example of the function $x \mapsto 1-e^{x}$ clearly shows that the statement $f=0$ is not true!