# Find all derivable functions such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)|≤|f(x)|,∀x∈\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Find all derivable functions $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)|≤|f(x)|,∀x∈\mathbb{R}$

I know the way is to use the Mean value theorem in an interval [0,1] and some how prove it is a contraction and iterating to the infinite we find something like f = 0, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $f(0)=0$ and $\left|f^\prime(x)\right|\leq\left|f(x)\right|$ imply $f(x)=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498898/does-f0-0-and-leftf-primex-right-leq-leftfx-right-imply-fx-0) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Cf%27(x)%7C≤%7Cf(x)%7C%24&p=1)

Comment: More similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1498898