# Show f is the zero function

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be continuous on $[0, +∞)$  and differentiable on $(0, +∞)$. If $f(0) = 0$
and $|f'(x)| < |f(x)|$ for all $x > 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x ≥ 0.$

I tried using the Mean Value Theorem for this but can't get anywhere significant.

Comment: As you wrote the question, it is impossible since if we let f(x) = 0, then |f'(x)| < 0 is impossible and is false.

Comment: I think the inequality should be weaker like $|f'(x) |\leq|f(x) |$

Comment: Also see the more general version https://math.stackexchange.com/q/399394/72031

Comment: It doesn't have to be weaker since f is only differentiable on $(0, \infty)$  so you can't compare at f(0)=0

Comment: And this is not the same question as the other one...

Answer (score 3):

**If $f'$ is integrable:**

\begin{align*}
|f(x)|&=\left|\int_{0}^{x}f'(t)dt\right|\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{x}|f'(t)|dt\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt.
\end{align*}
Now let $\varphi(x)=e^{-x}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt$, then 
\begin{align*}
\varphi'(x)=-e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt+e^{-x}|f(x)|=e^{-x}\left(|f(x)|-\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt\right)\leq 0,
\end{align*}
then 
\begin{align*}
\varphi(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\varphi'(t)dt\leq\int_{0}^{x}0dt=0,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt\leq 0,
\end{align*}
and hence 
\begin{align*}
|f(x)|\leq\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt\leq 0.
\end{align*}
Finally, we have $f(x)=0$.

Comment: You assume integrability of derivative. But otherwise it's ok.

Comment: Any other method to get rid of that?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please see the original and another linked question I gave in comment.

Comment: Don't say it's a duplicate because it looks similar because it is not. I've looked over and over and I can't use what's there to solve this one.