# Bellman-Gronwall inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

> Let $f(x)$ be differentiable over $[0,+\infty)$ and satisfy $f(0)=0$.
>   If there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $|f'(x)|\leq c|f(x)|$ holds
>   for every $x \in [0,+\infty)$, prove $f(x)\equiv 0.$

This is a version of **Bellman-Gronwall inequality**.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/509876/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Sir, the problem in your link is not the same as mine . The proof there depend on the existence of the maximum, which is not trivial for the present one.

Comment: It suffices to show that $f = 0$ on every interval $[0, b]$, because  then $f = 0$ on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: You can try the following, which seem different from the solutions provided by @Martin R:
 
 You have $$ f(x)^2=2\int_0^x f^{\prime}(t)f(t)dt\leq 2c\int_0^x (f(t))²dt$$
 Now put $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)^2dt$, $G(x)=F(x)\exp(-2cx)$, note that $G(0)=0$, $G(x)\geq 0$, and compute $G^{\prime}(x)$.

Comment: I consider using the auxilliary function $g(x):=e^{-cx}f(x)$, but how to deal with the absolute value sign?

Comment: @Kelenner Why do you not consider the absolute value sign？

Comment: You have
 
 You have $$ f(x)^2=|2\int_0^x f^{\prime}(t)f(t)dt|\leq2 \int_0^x |f^{\prime}(t)||f(t)|dt \leq ...$$

Comment: @Kelenner Thanks, but there exists a question left. $f'(x)$ is integrable ( in the meaning of Riemanne)? This seems to be not given from the assumption condition.

Comment: @mengdie1982 Yes, you have to suppose that $f^{\prime}(x)$ is for example continuous to have the integrability.

Comment: @Kelenner You say the statement does not hold without the continuity of $f'(x)$?

Comment: @mengdie1982 No; I say that my idea works only with the hypothesis of integrability (for example if $f^{\prime}$ is continuous )

Comment: @Kelenner: It seems that your idea works with the only assumption that $f$ is differentiable: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3569551/42969.

Comment: @mengdie1982: I have added an answer to the other question which covers infinite intervals directly.