# How to show that $f(x)=0 $ for all $x\in [0,1]?$

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from a sample paper of a entrance exam. I did this type of problems using MVT but this time i dont have any hint how to solve this
The question is
 "let $ f :[0,1]- R $ is differentiable and $ f(0)=0. $ Given that there exist a $c\in (0,1)$  such that $ |f'(x)|  \leq c|f(x)|$  for all $ x \in [0,1]. $ Then prove that $ f(x) =0$ for all $x\in [0,1].$

I was thinking if i can prove this by contradiction. That is if I assume $ f(x)>0 $ or $ f(x)<0 $ then by MVT i can arrive at a contradiction. But that's where i am stuck now since $c\in (0,1) $ then $c<1$  then $|f'(x)|<|f(x)|$  but i dont know what to do after that. Next i have some idea if i can show that $f'(x) = 0$  for all $x $ then $ f $ is a constant function and since $f(0)=0 $ then the whole function is zero
. That's why i need some hints to slove this problem.

Comment: $c\in(0,1)$ is written as `$c\in(0,1)$`, for example.  Please format your question.  Consult this:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: A more general version is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/399394/72031). Also see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1498898/72031).

Answer (score 6):

Hint: suppose the maximum absolute value of $f$ is attained at some $y\in [0,1]$ (by the extreme value theorem). Then 
\begin{equation}
\vert f(y)\vert=\bigg\vert \int_0^y f'(x)dx\bigg\vert\leq \int_0^y \vert f'(x)\vert dx\leq c\int_0^y \vert f(x)\vert dx\leq c\cdot y\cdot \vert f(y)\vert.
\end{equation}

What happens if $\vert f(y)\vert\neq 0$?

Comment: Thank you sir. But i have a question. How can you look at a sum like this and think of this kind of approach which is awesome. Can you suggest me any book of real analysis from where can i learn this kind of approach?

Comment: I’m glad you appreciate it! I don’t really have book suggestions; these sorts of things are more experience than anything else as opposed to a technique in some book. Personally, my thought process was just if you want to relate a derivative and the original function, the fundamental theorem of calculus is probably relevant. Hope this helps!

Comment: $c<1$ is also not necessary in this proof after a small modification, you just end up having to repeat the argument on a few intervals of length less than $1/c$.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in a comment, I'm not sure what is wrong with the answer of Eeyore Ho. Here is an elaboration.

Considering instead the differentiable function $g:=f^2=|f|^2$, we note that the assumptions imply
$$ g' \le 2c g$$

One can now use Gronwall's inequality to finish, or indeed just follow the proof of Gronwall's inequality. Consider the function

$$ h(x) = g(x)e^{-2cx}$$
then
$$ h'(x) = (g'(x)-2c g(x))e^{2cx} \le 0$$
So $h$ is non-increasing. But $h(0) = 0 $ and $h\ge 0$, so $h(x)=0$ for all $x$; so $g(x)=0$ for all $x$, so $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

PS this doesn't require $c\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the mean value theorem.

Let $a\in [0,1]$ we have by MVT $a_1\in [0,a]$ such that  $\frac{f(a)- f(0)}{a} = f'(a_1)\leq c f(a_1)$ thus $f(a) \leq ac f(a_1)$

Again for $a_1 \in [0,a_1]$ we have $a_2\in [0,a_1]$ such that $\frac{f(a_1)-f(0)}{a_1-0} = f'(a_2) \leq c f(a_2)$ combine the first and the second we get

$f(a) \leq ac f(a_1) \leq aa_1c^2f(a_2)$  (note that $c\in (0,1)$ also $a,a_1 \leq 1$ )
So $f(a) \leq c^2 f(a_1)$ keep going we get

$f(a) \leq c^n f(a_n)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f^{2}(x),\, g(x)\geq 0,$

$$\left |g^{'}(x)\right |\leq 2cg(x)$$
Prove $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]. $
And then you can get
$ f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]. $

Comment: Why does this have a downvote? The only thing not explicitly said is an application of Gronwall's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grönwall%27s_inequality